# How to deploy python module extension

Tags: python, deployment

I deploy my app with `virtualenv --no-site-packages` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`. There is `feedgen` module in requirements, that has `site-packages/feedgen/ext` directory with extensions. Among other, I deploy `foobar.py` extension for feedgen, and the answer is:

What is the best practice to deploy module's lib? In case of, e.g., Heroku, AWS,etc

Is it ok to use `setup.py`? Or `Makefile`? Or shell-script to copy file? Or what else?

PS I,m not ready to contribute to `feedgen` yet, as my code is still 'smells'. (I understand that so the problem would be solved by itself)

Answer (score 0):

The most popular practice is to put a module on pypi and be able to install it with pip. The second way is cloning from github and running `python setup.py install`. The second way is usually used for installation from source and the first often provides compiled wheels that do not need compilation.

If you do not want to share the code you could use installation from files in pip and use private git repositories instead of github.

An example from `pyarrow`:

Usual installation from pip is written on [this page](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html):

```
pip install pyarrow
```

[Installation from source](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#python-development). Here it is a Cython module so the author uses build_ext instead of install

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
...
cd arrow/python
...
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Comment: @keiv-fly, thanks. Your advice with `git clone`  and `build_ext` sounds proper.